# Is writing considered a volunteer job? Is it worth mentioning it?

Tags: linkedin, volunteering

I am contributing a lot in a wikipedia-like service, which is mostly driven by the community. I am writing, editing, reviewing the articles etc.

What would you think(in a hypothetical recruiter role), if I would put as a volunteer work in my CV/LinkedIn? 
What would you think(in a hypothetical recruiter role), if I would put it as a professional experience in my CV/LinkedIn?

Comment: I think it would depend on what type of job you are applying for or trying to attract. Is it applicable to your dream job? Can you expand on what type of articles you are editing? are they technical, or about a certain type of expertise you have?

Comment: Are the skills that you are using/ developing in this role relevant to the sorts of positions that you're applying for?  Is this role the best way of demonstrating those skills?

Comment: I am a software engineer, so I am focusing on the technical section mostly, yes. 
Writing article is not crucial for software people, but it is a good way to prove my English writing skills(I am not native)

Comment: This is a pretty confused problem statement. By definition, you're a volunteer if and only if your contributions are *voluntary*. You can even receive some forms of compensation—but volunteering is *not* a job and it is *not* "professional" in terms of earning a wage or salary (or operating a business).

Comment: @Air, I agree with you...my view is that most hiring managers/recruiters, appreciate such actions, though.

Comment: @py_script - In my experience they would only care if the expect their technical people to write technical documents.  If it cannot benefit the company, then you volunteering for Wikipedia, isn't going to get almost no good will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would you think(in a hypothetical recruiter role), if I would put as a volunteer work in my CV/LinkedIn?

Communication is one of the most important skills for a software engineer. If I were to review your application and you linked to articles you've written, I would definitely read a few of them. If they're well-written, and I (think I) understood what you were explaining, that's obviously a plus.

> if I would put it as a professional experience in my CV/LinkedIn?

then I would think you were paid by some company to write those? Maybe to plant advertising or wrong information? (These things happen...) My first thought would probably be something unethical. If you didn't get paid, don't put it under professional experience.

Comment: Nice view, thanks for sharing...to be honest I am mostly towards putting as volunteering.

Comment: You can put volunteer experience at the end of your resume.